# Regex to get digits from a string when there is no separator between digits

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like `Acc:123-456-789` and another string like -1234567, I need your help to write an expression to match digits in case there is no separator between the digits.

```
-*(?!\d*(?:\d*-)$)\d*$
```

Input strings:

```
Acc:123-456-789   -12323232 7894596
```

Desired result:

```
group 1 12323232 
group 2 7894596
```

Comment: please spend 2 minutes learning [how to format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) the post. `*` is not a normal character so it messed up the string

Comment: Maybe all you need is `^-?[0-9]+$`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this ought to work:

```
(?<=^|\s|\s-)(\d+)(?=\s|$)
```

Breaking it down:

- `(?<=^|\s|\s-)` - A positive lookbehind that matches the start of the string, whitespace, or whitespace followed by a `-`.
- `(\d+)` - Matches and captures number sequences.
- `(?=\s|$)` - A positive lookahead that matches whitespace or the end of the string.

** Note: If you need to capture negative number sequences, replace `(\d+)` with `(\-?\d+)`.

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/VFEUTG/1)

[Regex reference](http://regexstorm.net/reference)

Remember for use in C# that you need to escape backslashes or use the `@` prefix to a string literal (`@"  "`).